# Could there be a way to make the Tor network faster by paying money?

Tags: onion-routing, protocol, bandwidth, garlic-routing

Suppose someone has a lot of monero (or some other sufficiently private currency) and they want to have highest possible data throughput while maintaining anonymity.

Has anyone researched protocols that allow someone to pay for packet prioritization but in such a way that they can still remain anonymous. I understand that simply marking your packets as "special" is basically the definition of de-anonymization. So in order to make this work there would need to be a probabilistic component to it/someone pays to make MANY users packets higher priority (and not just their own), to retain their anonymity.

I suspect a protocol like this should exist. Perhaps this question is also better suited for cyber security stackexchange or crypto.stackexchange but this seemed like the best place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed! run a node or two - and it will make the whole network a bit faster

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You will probably want to see these two blog posts:
https://blog.torproject.org/two-incentive-designs-tor
https://blog.torproject.org/tor-incentives-research-roundup-goldstar-par-braids-lira-tears-and-torcoin